# Erro "bash: ruby: command not found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou tentando instalar o Ruby on Rails no Windows, mas eu instalo e sempre que vou tentar usar o Git BASH na pasta "Sites" que é criada na instalação, aparece esse erro. Como posso arrumar?

Comando que eu tento rodar: ruby -v

Comment: que comando você está digitando? por favor [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/221172/edit) sua pergunta e inclua o comando e o erro completo =]

Comment: atualizei a pergunta :)

Comment: por favor inclua o resultado do seguinte comando: `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O mais provável é que o programa não esteja listado no seu `PATH`.

Você precisa verificar a pasta onde o `Ruby` foi instalado, por exemplo:

> C:\Ruby22-x64

Descoberto isso, você precisa adicionar a pasta `bin` no seu `path`.

### Modo 1:

Vá no `executar` <kbd>⊞ Win+R</kbd> e digite:

> *SystemPropertiesAdvanced*

Então clique em:

> Variáveis de Ambiente (*Environment Variables*, em inglês)

E então dentro de `Variáveis de usuário` (*User variables* em inglês), dê dois cliques em `Path`, clique em "Novo" (*New* em inglês) e adicione a seguinte linha (substituindo pelo caminho da sua instalação):

> C:\Ruby22-x64\bin

### Modo 2:

No `prompt de comando`, digite:

> echo %path%>path.txt

Para termos um *backup* do `path` atual e então:

> setx path "%path%;C:\Ruby22-x64\bin"

Substituindo, é claro, o endereço pelo da sua instalação.

---

#### Cuidado com o comando setx - ele pode apagar seu path!